# musicg-sound-api on Android

Tags: java, android

musicg-sound-api when use on Android and use **FrequencyTimeDomainRepresentation** class it show error about **`"Could not find class java.awt.image.BufferedImage"`**. But BufferedImage class don't have in Android sdk.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

java.awt.image.BufferedImage is part of the AWT package in JDK. However this package is not part of the Android API's. Android has its Graphics Package. Try to replace this class with anything from [this package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/package-summary.html)